# Can I connect android(Eclipse) to SQL Server(2005) using php web services?

Tags: php, android, sql, eclipse, json

I have read a number of questions on this site itself on accessing db from android.
But I still can't make out if I can connect android(Eclipse) to SQL Server(2005) using php web services?

I am required to connect an android app to SQL server and I am familiar with using JSON and PHP web services to connect to MySQL Server.

Most sites suggest to use B4A and ASP.Net  to connect to SQL Server ,which I don't know.How about using Eclipse and ASP.Net (Well, that requires me to learn ASP.Net )?

What would be the differences in connecting to SQL server than MySQL server?

Comment: is it going to be the same connecting to SQL server and mysql server??When i did research on connecting android and SQL Server ,no site suggests this combination of Eclipse-PHP-SQL Server,rather they give B4A-ASP.Net/PHP-Sql server..

Comment: There are three different parts: an Android app, that is communicating with PHP web service, the PHP web service that is connected to MS SQL server, and MS SQL server. You have to use apropriate DB driver for PHP to be able to connect to MS SQL and google for PHP + MS SQL connection. The rest (Java <-JSON-> PHP) is OK for You, I guess...

Comment: hey its not about connecting android to SQL Server or MySql , they both are the same , configure yout android application to make  httpget/httppost request to the web service , now it depends on the web secvice whether you want it to be some ASP application or java application

Comment: I am asked to develop an android app for an existing .NET app.But i prefer to work on the JAVA platform..

Answer (score 2):

Connection to a MySQL server and a MSSQL server should just be using a different database driver in PHP. For example mysql would use mysql_connect and mssql would use mssql_connect. What you use for a database should not matter for your android application. Your android application is isolated on your phone unless you want to use a database on the phone like SQLlite. For your situation you will want to create a restful API that you android application can call. I have done the same thing in my own android application that connects to a restful api. I use json to pass the data back and forth you can also use XML. I just find json to be easier to work with. No need to a SOAP web service then. Think of a web service as a location you setup to execute a set of php commands and then return a result it's as simple as that.

Comment: +1 good answer only you mistyped this sentence in a bad way: "... use mysql_connect and mssql would use *mysql*_connect...."